# Access redis remotely.

Tags: bash, redis, debian, remote-access

I´m trying to remotely access my redis database that is hosted on my little Debian server but I can´t get it to work. Hopefully someone can help me out with this one.

Here are the steps I took.

I´ve set up my redis according to [this](http://grainier.net/how-to-install-redis-in-ubuntu/) tutorial.
Using the provided setup shell script I got the following log showing all created directories/files:

```
Port : 6379
Config file : /etc/redis/6379.conf
Log file : /var/log/redis_6379.log
Data dir : /var/lib/redis/6379
Executable : /usr/local/bin/redis-server
Cli Executable : /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

Now I´m able to start/stop/restart with `service redis_6379 start/stop/restart`.
At this point I´m able to connect to my redis *locally*.

```
root@smg:/home/local: redis-cli ping
PONG
```

This is the output of my log.

```
12505:M 11 Jun 16:18:48.248 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
12505:M 11 Jun 16:18:48.248 # Server initialized
12505:M 11 Jun 16:18:48.248 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
12505:M 11 Jun 16:18:48.249 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
12505:M 11 Jun 16:18:48.249 * Ready to accept connections
```

I went ahead and modified the bind setting in `redis/6379.conf` under Networking to bind to `bind 0.0.0.0` which should allow all IPs to connect to my server using port 6379.
Also I´ve set an incoming rule for iptables which looks like this `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT`.
I can provide full iptables log if needed.

I rebooted my redis. Checking with `ps aux | grep redis` I am confirmed that my server is running.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND    
root     12505  0.0  0.1  43216  4008 ?        Ssl  16:18   0:08 /usr/local/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

I now check if my redis is really listening on all ports. So I check with `netstat -nlpt | grep 6379` and get the following output. I think that the output is confirming that redis is listening for all external IPs but I´m not quite sure.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12505/redis-server
```

Basically everything is set up now for remote connections but if I try to connect from my server I get a Connection Timeout.

```
root@smg:/home/local: redis-cli -h [serverIP]
Could not connect to Redis at [serverIP]:6379: Connection timed out
```

I´ve seen a `Connection Refused` error in many threads here on StackOverflow but nothing that is concerned about a Connection Timeout.

I really have no idea why I get this Timeout. Hopefully one of you knows more about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `telnet` to connect to `6379`. For example `telnet <host> 6379`. If you get a message like `Connected to <host>.` you at least know the port is open and listening. If not, you need to find out if you have an OS firewall or something else causing the block. It would appear, based on your info here, that redis is running and listening on 6379, so something else must be getting in the way.

Comment: Hey Brandon, I´ve followed your tip and tried to connect using `telnet`. At first connection was denied because redis was still in protected mode. I´ve changed that in the config to `protected-mode no`. Now I´m able to connect to that port from an external pc but still I get that Connection Timeout calling `redis-cli -h <host>` :/

Any idea where the problem could be now?

Comment: Are you getting any errors about redis in your logs on the server?

Comment: Nope actually nothing. Still `Ready to accept connections`

Comment: I already changed the `somaxconn` and `vm.overcommit_memory` according to Meiram down below and it helped to get rid of the warnings in the log but still the timeout error occurs

Comment: Are you able to connect to redis locally on the redis server?

Comment: yes i can. actually it´s really strange now. I can ping redis server from external machine using telnet. Also the threads I´m using for my project are connecting to redis remotely. so only connecting with `redis-cli -h <redis server ip>` from the redis server fails

Comment: Doesn't sound like you are running redis on a VPS, but I have been fighting the same issue most of today with my VPS Ubuntu server, until that is I found the Firewall policies section on the control panel from my provider. Set 6379 up as an exception and bingo, connected to redis. Doesn't look like doing anything on ufw makes any difference on the actual server (all the http/apache ports were open by default). Maybe this can help ?

Answer (score 0):

my friend.

WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.

Change /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535
```

In the /etc/sysctl.conf change to **vm.overcommit_memory = 1**

Comment: Hi, I just set the 2 values you said. The warning disappear from the log but still I get a Connection Timeout : /

Comment: check disk size df -h

Comment: still got some space left

`root@smg:/etc/redis# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       22G  4.5G   16G  22% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           401M  5.5M  396M   2% /run
tmpfs          1002M  4.0K 1002M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1002M     0 1002M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           201M     0  201M   0% /run/user/1000`

Comment: try telnet localhost 6379

Answer (score 0):

`Connection timed out` means your local machine is not able to access `6379` port of your redis machine. Check firewall rules (`security groups` if you are using AWS or `Firewall rules` if you are using GCP ) for your redis machine and allow `6379` port of redis machine for your source machine.